# Is it possible to remove string-valued JSON nodes from a JObject variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I am using .NET 4.7, MVC5, C# and JSON.NET

I have a JObject variable called "json"

```
JObject jsonPerson = JObject.Parse(strPersonsDetails);
```

It contains nodes with same name, but different structure:

```
name : "Joe Bloggs"
```

and

```
name : {
        firstname : "Joe",
        lastname : "Bloggs"
        }
```

I would like to remove any node that are of type string ie :

```
name : "Joe Bloggs"
```

and leave  :

```
name : {
        firstname : "Joe",
        lastname : "Bloggs"
        }
```

which is of type "name"

Is there any way to remove all properties called "name" which have a text value as opposed to the other version that has a complex type of type "name" from `jsonPerson`?

EDIT:

More complete JSON:

```
{
"items": [
         {
         "id" : 1,
         "name" : "Joe Bloggs"
         },
         {
         "id" : 2,
         "name" : {
                  "FirstName" : "Joe",
                  "LastName" : "Bloggs"
                  }
          }
          ]
}
```

Comment: I want to remove all properties called "name" which have a text value as opposed to the other version that has a complex type of type "name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine a [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) query to select the values of all relevant `"name"` nodes in your JSON hierarchy, then filter those for which [`JToken.Type`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Type.htm) is [`JTokenType.String`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenType.htm).  Then you can [remove](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Remove.htm) them from their parent `JObject` by removing the containing `JProperty`.

The following code does the job:

```
// Select the values of all relevant "name" nodes using a JSONPath query, 
// https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/
// Then select only those whose which are of type string.
var query = jsonPerson
    .SelectTokens("..name")
    .Where(t => t.Type == JTokenType.String);

query.ToList().ForEach(t => t.RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent());
```

Using the extension method:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JToken RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return null;
        // If the parent is a JProperty, remove that instead of the token itself.
        var contained = node.Parent is JProperty ? node.Parent : node;
        contained.Remove();
        // Also detach the node from its immediate containing property -- Remove() does not do this even though it seems like it should
        if (contained is JProperty)
            ((JProperty)node.Parent).Value = null;
        return node;
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s6RThS).

Notes:

- I used the JSONPath recursive descent operator `..` to select the values of *all* properties named `name` anywhere in the JSON hierarchy.  Assuming your JSON has a fairly fixed schema you might want to simplify that to select the `name` nodes at their expected location in the hierarchy:

  ```
  var query = jsonPerson
      .SelectTokens("items[*].name")
      .Where(t => t.Type == JTokenType.String);
  ```

  Where `*` is the wildcard operator selecting all array entries. Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OMwt4R).
- [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) returns the selected property *values*.  In order to remove those values from the hierarchy it is necessary to remove the containing `JProperty`.  The extension method `JsonExtensions.RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent()` does this.

Comment: I have added a more complete example if this affects your answer in any way. Thanks for the comprehensive reply, actually amazing reply..... :)

Comment: To be more specific, can I alter the path to "SelectTokens("items.name") ?

Comment: No, because the value of `items` is an array.  You need to use `"items[*].name"` to pick out all array values.  Demo fiddle #2 here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OMwt4R