# Remove JSON child

Tags: json.net

I have a JSON in this format below. How can I remove the **""xLogic":"redirect""** 
using VB.NET with Newtonsoft?:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "abc":"test",
         "def":0.2525829100335102
      }
   ],
   "input":{  
      "text":"Less than"
   },
   "context":{  
      "xLogic":"redirect",
      "form-type":"abc",
      "form-people":"100"
   }
}
```

I tried (str_Response_Final is the json):

```
Dim obj_Json_final As JObject = JObject.Parse(str_Response_Final)
obj_Json_final.Property("context")("xLogic").Remove()
```

But not working.

Comment: Your problem is that `obj_Json_final.Property("context")("xLogic")` returns the **value** of the property `xLogic` but you need to remove the containing `JProperty`, not the `JValue` itself.  To do this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57191951/3744182) to [Is it possible to remove string-valued JSON nodes from a JObject variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57191505/3744182).  Of course that's a c# answer, please let us know if you need a vb.net answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be the following.

```
Dim jObject = CType(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json), Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)
Dim propertyToRemove As JProperty = Nothing

For Each item In jObject.[Property]("context").Value.[Select](Function(x) TryCast(x, JProperty))
     Dim objAsConvertible As JProperty = TryCast(item, JProperty)
        If objAsConvertible IsNot  Nothing Then
           If objAsConvertible.Name.Equals("xLogic") Then propertyToRemove = objAsConvertible
    End If


Next
propertyToRemove.Remove()
Dim result As String = jobject.ToString()
```

Comment: I try this way, is seems to work. Is there any potential issue?     

      ```Dim obj_Json_final As JObject = JObject.Parse(str_Response_Final)  
     'remove xLogic  
     Dim obj_context As JObject = obj_Json_final.SelectToken("context")  
  
            If obj_context.Property("xLogic") IsNot Nothing Then  
                obj_context.Property("xLogic").Remove()  
            End If ```